# How to pass throwable object with "401 unauthorised exception"?

Tags: java, android, exception, throwable

I have a callback method in my java class which is expecting a `Throwable` object to be passed. The `Exception` should be `401 unauthorised exception`. How can I achieve this ?

```
if ((currentTime - refreshTime) < (expiresInFromPrefs - 5)) {
                //token is live
                tokenCallback.success(accessTokenFromPrefs);
            }else{
                //token expired
//                Throwable throwable = new AuthFailureError()
                Log.e(TAG,"token expired");
                tokenCallback.failure(Throwable object);
            }
```

`tokenCallback.failure()` is expecting Throwable object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `Throwable` object with your message.

```
new Throwable("401 unauthorised exception");
```

So,

```
tokenCallback.failure(new Throwable("401 unauthorised exception"));
```

Comment: it crashed..it was expecting some `Id`.

Comment: @XoXo you might have some other issue, I haven't done something special except what you asked for.

Comment: Is there any other way to pass an `Exception` object. Something like if a network call fails we get `onError` callback with `error object` which consist of `NetworkResponse` or the reason for exception.

Comment: @XoXo I really don't know what is happening with your app. If I would something you will come back again with some other issue. And I won't have any idea, what are you doing. So, as I said, you should post new question with details (include exception stacktrace).